# MUI Form Fields not updating error state until I click on them

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js13, mui-x

I have been working on this for almost two days, and feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I have a form that makes an API call, but before, it validates whether fields are correct. I'm using NextJS 14, MUI, and Typescript. The error state of the form is updated inside of an object `formErrorState`

My form acts normal the first time I try to submit it. I'm using MUI fields, Textfield and FormControl with `error=` prop set equal to a boolean `formErrorState.fieldname`

The first time I try to submit my form, if there are any errors, the error fields properly turn red and display helper text as I would expect. But if I go ahead and fix some of the errors, and try to submit again, the fields that had `error` state set to false before (but now have an error) will not turn red.

So for example,

I have three fields:

- Models
- Variables
- Counties

Let's say I try to submit my form with `Models` and `Counties` correctly filled, but with an error in the `Variables` field. In that case, my `Variables` field turns red, and the form won't be submitted. At this point, I come in and fix my `Variables` but make a change in `Counties` that makes it have an error. The next time I try to submit, I would expect `Variables` to not be red again, and for `Counties` to turn red. But instead, `Variables` is correctly changing back to a regular state, and `Counties` stays as it is, without any error displayed, even though `formErrorState.counties` has been set equal to `true`

One interesting thing is that if I click on any of the trouble (has an error) `Textfields`, the field correctly switches to red. But I don't see that behavior when I click inside the trouble `FormControl`

Here is my code:

```
interface FormFieldErrorStates {
    models: boolean;
    vars: boolean;
    counties: boolean;
}


const myComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = (..props) => {
    const [formErrorState, setFormErrorState] = useState<FormFieldErrorStates>({
        models: false,
        vars: false,
        counties: false
    })

    let isFormInvalid: boolean = false
    // tried to store isFormInvalid as a state object, and was having issues due to the asynchronous nature of useState()

    const validateFormData = () => {
        let newFormErrorState: FormFieldErrorStates = formErrorState
    
        if(...errors in Models field) {
            newFormErrorState.models = true
        } else {
            newFormErrorState.models = false
        }

        if(...errors in Variables field) {
            newFormErrorState.variables = true
        } else {
            newFormErrorState.variables = false
        }

        if(...errors in Counties field) {
            newFormErrorState.counties = true
        } else {
            newFormErrorState.counties = false
        }

        setFormErrorState(newFormErrorState)
        isFormInvalid = searchValueInObject(formErrorState, true) // Searches for any true flags in the error state object
    
    }
    
    const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        validateFormData()

        if (!isFormInvalid) {
           // make API call

           ifFormInvalid = false
        }
    }
}
```

Up to here, the code seems to mostly work. The form isn't submitted unless validation passes. And the first time I try to submit, my error fields display correctly. But as I explained it gets complicated after that. Here's the code for my MUI form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    // models
    <FormControl error={formErrorState.models}>
        <Select>
            <MenuItem>Model 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Model 2</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        {formErrorState.models && <p className="error">Error in models</p>}
    </FormControl>

    // counties
    <Autocomplete
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} error={formErrorState.counties} />
        )}
    </Autocomplete>

    // variables
    <Autocomplete
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} error={formErrorState.variables} />
        )}
    </Autocomplete>

    <Button onClick={() => {handleSubmit()}} variant="contained">Submit</Button>
</form>
```

Could it be that I need to figure out a way to re-render the inputs everytime `validateFormData()` runs? I thought that automatically changing the error flags would trigger a change of state in the inputs.

I've tried a few different variations of this to no avail. Let me know if you have any ideas.